# shell ftp upload - file corrupted

Tags: image, shell, upload, ftp

I'm a shell noob. I'm trying to write a simple script that'll take a screen shot and upload it to my server, this all works great when I do it line by line in my terminal, but when I try to achieve this via my simple script the file that gets uploaded seems to be corrupted. I've compared the two files (the corrupted file that gets uploaded as a result of my script and the non-corrupted file that gets uploaded when I do this manually) in a hex editor and their nearly identical... but not. Any idea what's happening to my images when I run the script that isn't happing when I do the same thing line by line in the terminal?

here's my script:

```
    #!/bin/sh

    screencapture -x ~/Desktop/screencap.png

    HOST='mysite.com'
    USER='myUsrName'
    PASSWD='myPassWord'
    DIR='DESKTOP_CAPS'
    FILE='screencap.png'

    ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
    quote USER $USER
    quote PASS $PASSWD
    cd $DIR
    put $FILE
    quit
    END_SCRIPT
    exit 0
```

thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `binary` command to set the mode of file transfer to binary
(the binary mode transmits all eight bits per byte and thus provides less chance of a transmission error and must be used to transmit files other than ASCII files)